# why use backlog in socket_listen()

Tags: php, sockets

[**socket_listen()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-listen.php)

I was see the manual of `socket_listen()`.Still i don't get the point of

```
bool socket_listen ( resource $socket [, int $backlog = 0 ] )
```

> 1.What is the backlogs in this case ?
>
> 2.And Why use with socket_listen() and what is use of it?
>
> 3.What happen `backlogs` remove from `socket_listen()`
>
> > 4. Why use the backlog values like `0,1,2,3`?

kindly explain the above question.

Thanks

Comment: It's been two years :) Don't you think I answered your question? Maybe, it's time to accept the answer? ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is wrong with how `$backlog` is covered in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-listen.php)?

> A maximum of backlog incoming connections will be queued for processing. If a connection request arrives with the queue full the client may receive an error with an indication of `ECONNREFUSED`, or, if the underlying protocol supports retransmission, the request may be ignored so that retries may succeed.
>
> **Note:**
> The maximum number passed to the backlog parameter highly depends on the underlying platform. On Linux, it is silently truncated to `SOMAXCONN`. On win32, if passed `SOMAXCONN`, the underlying service provider responsible for the socket will set the backlog to a maximum reasonable value. There is no standard provision to find out the actual backlog value on this platform.

Or you could refer to [BSD Sockets listen documentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets#listen), since PHP uses BSD sockets:

> an integer representing the number of pending connections that can be queued up at any one time. The operating system usually places a cap on this value.

BSD sockets historically use a single queue implementation, the size of which is determined by the backlog argument.

When a `SYN` packet is received from a client, it sends back a `SYN/ACK` packet and adds the connection to the queue. When the corresponding `ACK` is received, the connection changes its state to `ESTABLISHED` and becomes eligible for handover to the application.

When the maximum backlog is reached, the system will no longer send back `SYN/ACK` packets in response to `SYN` packets. Usually the TCP implementation will simply drop the `SYN` packet (instead of responding with a `RST` packet) so that the client will retry. Hence that "**may** receive an error with an indication of `ECONNREFUSED`"

If you do not use `backlog` argument in your implementation, it will simply be set automatically. On Linux it's **128**, as of [listen man page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/listen):

> If the backlog argument is greater than the value in `/proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn`, then it is silently truncated to that value; the default value in this file is 128. In kernels before 2.4.25, this limit was a hard coded value, `SOMAXCONN`, with the value 128.

Comment: I am not say wrong this php manual. Why use the backlog values like `0,1,2,3` What is the use of it?

Comment: I think I fully covered this in my answer. You use `backlog` to limit the number of incoming connections at one time. Isn't it obvious?